# How many bytes are used for a user connection?

Tags: sql-server

I cannot find in MS doc the amount of bytes that is taken by default by SQL Server.

has anyone some information about that point ?

Comment: Why do you think it could possibly be *relevant*? Are you experiencing a *problem*, and if so, have you done something that leads you to believe that connection memory usage is the cause? If so, please share a) the problem and b) the logic you followed to reach that conclusion.

Comment: I have no conclusion at the moment, but one of my customer use a Standard version with more than 5,000 users which is limited to 128 Gb of cache. Due to very bad design (obese tables and massive usage of scalar UDF and SQL CLR ones) there is a  big problem of cache and I would like to know how many bytes are taken by default when a connection is done...

Comment: See [this {old} doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/aa337559(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). It will be about 12K with a 4K packet size.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks very much, that was the page I was looking for !

Comment: 128Gb refers *only* to the buffer pool (where cached database pages live) https://blog.sqlxdetails.com/max-memory-in-sql-server-2016-standard-edition/ other server objects, such as the small amount used by a connection, use a separate section of memory. I would love to know the relevance of scalar UDFs to buffer pool, obviously badly written SQLCLR *can* affect it

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/aa337559(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Given by Dan Guzman.
Thanks !